# showing the text of only a few interval levels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, intervals

```
c1 <- c("p2","p3","p1","p2","p1","p3","p4","p4","p4","p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p4","p2","p1","p4","p3","p3")
c2 <- c(41,146,79,107,131,127,32,88,119,148,32,65,36,23,44,76,100,98,121,104)
df <- data.frame(c1=c1, c2=c2)
c <- mutate(df, c2.intervals = cut(c2, breaks = c(0, 30, 50, 70,120,150)))
ggplot(aes(x = c2.intervals, fill = c1), data=c) + geom_histogram(stat="count")
```

This shows the text for all intervals in the x axis. I would like to show the text of some of the levels, say `(30,50]`, and `(70,120]`, while plotting all bins. In other words is there an easy way to hide the text of some levels of `c2.intervals` in ggplot2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

---

#### Variant 1 (manual)

[image: 1]

```
ggplot(aes(x = c2.intervals, fill = c1), data = c) + 
    geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("", "(30,50]", "", "(70,120))", ""))
```

---

#### Variant 2 (show every n-th)

[image: 1]

```
xlabels <- levels(c$c2.intervals)
xlabels[seq(1, length(xlabels), 2)] <- ""

ggplot(aes(x = c2.intervals, fill = c1), data = c) + 
    geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = xlabels)
```

---

#### Data

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

c1 <- c("p2","p3","p1","p2","p1","p3","p4","p4","p4","p1","p1","p2","p2","p3","p4","p2","p1","p4","p3","p3")
c2 <- c(41,146,79,107,131,127,32,88,119,148,32,65,36,23,44,76,100,98,121,104)
df <- data.frame(c1 = c1, c2 = c2)
c <- mutate(df, c2.intervals = cut(c2, breaks = c(0, 30, 50, 70, 120, 150)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman. Yes that's the effect, but I was looking for a way that doesn't require manually defining which labels I want to keep. With just four intervals that's fine, but my actual data set have many more, and I might need to change which labels I want to show. If `c2.intervals` were continuous I could do `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1000, 10))` for example. I was hoping there would be something similar for interval data.

Comment: In what way would you like to define which interval to keep? E.g., every 2nd? Or specific ones that you want to choose?

Comment: Yes, for example showing the label of every second interval. How would you modify the code above to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @HappyPy it's also certainly possible. Check it out. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for!